# Powershell script to move files based on a source list (.txt

Tags: powershell

I have thousands of files in a directory (.pdf, .xls, .doc) and they all have a similar naming convention (the "type" is always a constant string, ie: billing or invoice);

**accountname**_**accountnumber**_type.pdf

**accountname**_ **accountnumber**_type.doc

**accountname**_**accountnumber**_type.xls

The task at hand is to receive a random list of accountnames and account numbers (the "type" is always a constant, ie: billing, invoice, shipping or order and they vary in format) and move them from Directory A into Directory B. I can get the list into a .csv file to match the **accountname_accountnumber**_type.

I have been trying to create a powershell script to reference the accountname_accountnumber and move those items from one directory A to directory B with no luck.

**SAMPLE** I found something a bit simpler, but I wanted to be able to edit this to create a new destination and not halt if the file is not found from this list. Also, if I could have this pick from a .txt list I think that would be easier than pasting everything.

```
$src_dir = "C:\DirA\"
$dst_dir = "D:\DirB-mm-dd-yyyy\" #This code requires the destination dir to already be there and I need to have the code output a new Directory, it could output based on date script run that would be amazing

$file_list = "accountname1_accountnumber001_type", #If I can select to import csv here
"accountname2_accountnumber002_type",
"accountname3_accountnumber003_type",
"accountname4_accountnumber004_type",
"accountname5_accountnumber005_type",
"accountname6_accountnumber006_type"

foreach ($file in $file_list) #This errors out and stops the script if the file is not located in source and I need to have the script continue and move on, with hopefully an error output
{
  move-Item $src_dir$file $dst_dir
}
```

They can be any file format, I am trying to get the code to match ONLY the accountname and accountnumber since those two will define the exact customer. Whether it is invoice, billing or shipping doesn't matter since they want all files associated with that customer moved.

For Example there could be 4 of each for every account and the type format may vary from pdf, doc and xls, I need to move all files based on their first two indicators (accountname,accountnumber).

alice_001_invoice.pdf

alice_001_billing.doc

alice_001_shipping.pdf

alice_001_order.xls

George_245_invoice.pdf

George_245_billing.doc

George_245_shipping.pdf

George_245_order.xls

Bob_876_invoice.pdf

Bob_876_billing.doc

Bob_876_shipping.pdf

Bob_876_order.xls

Horman_482_invoice.pdf

Horman_482_billing.doc

Horman_482_shipping.pdf

Horman_482_order.xls

**CSV:**

accountname,accountnumber

Alice,001

George,245

Bob,876

Horman,482

Comment: Perhaps if you include your code so far, we can help you better.

Comment: how about this: `cd $SourceDir ; ls *_*_type.* | Move-Item -Destination $DestinationDir -WhatIf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this :

```
$CurrentDate = [DateTime]::Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")
$DestinationDir = "D:\DirB-$CurrentDate"
New-Item $DestinationDir -ItemType Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$AccountToMove = Import-CSV $CSVPath
Foreach ( $Account In $AccountToMove ){
    $FilePattern = "*$($Account.AccountName)*$($Account.AccountNumber)*"
    ls $SourceDir | Where Name -like $FilePattern | Move-Item -Destination $DestinationDir
}
```

Comment: I will definitely test this out later today, it looks as though it should do the trick =)

Answer (score 0):

The code part - you already edited off from the post - about moving files to subdirectories doesn't make much sense with your business rules. As you never show the sample CSV file contents, it's all guessing.

For easier processing, assume you got the following source files. Edit your post to show the CSV file contents and where you would like to move the files.

```
C:\some\path\A\Alice_001_bill.doc
C:\some\path\A\Alice_001_invoice.xls
C:\some\path\A\Bob_002_invoice.pdf
C:\some\path\A\Bob_002_invoice.doc
C:\some\path\A\Eve_003_bill.xls
C:\some\path\A\Eve_003_invoice.doc
```

Comment: Did that help explain a little bit more?

Comment: @user3583862 Close, but no cigar. The destination description is still missing. Where would you move, say, Bob's files?

Comment: All files in the input text would be moved, based on the accountname and accountnumber. Bob, Alice, Horman and George would all be moved into a new DIR based on the date the script was executed. I'm trying to figure out how to get this script to create a new Directory for the destination based on the script execution date.