# powershell move files based on csv contents

Tags: excel, powershell, pdf, csv

Hi All and thanks for helping!

I have produced a set of PDF files which are all saved in

L:\ClientSort\

Each of these files has a naming convention in the following way

XXX_A123456_YYY.PDF
XXX_300123123_YYY.PDF

(the xxx stands for the brand)
the yyy stands for account type)

What I need to do is move these PDF's into one of two directories based on criteria within a CSV, excel or text file.

I will perform the logic of where the files should be sent within this file and within column D provide the file location to which I want to move the PDF.

Please see the attached spreadsheet to further clarify this point.

Basically...   If the PDF naming convention contains the account number in column A, I need to move the file to the location specified in column D.

I have looked at as many different solutions as possible and the closed I could find was
[Link to poss solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23356289/powershell-script-to-move-files-based-on-a-source-list-txt)

Anyone have any ideas how this may be achieved?

The code I have created comes from multiple sources but I do not have enough knowledge of Powershell at this time to get any further with this.

```
Set-Location “L:\ClientSort”

$Folders = Import-Csv L:\ClientDataSort.csv 

ForEach($Folder in $Folders) {

New-Item $Folder.folders -type directory

}


$text = Import-Csv “L:\ClientDataSort.csv” 

$dir = Get-ChildItem L:\ClientSort

foreach($item in $text ){

foreach ($folder in $dir) {

#where Package is the name of the column in the csv file and FileName the name of #second column in the input csv file
#I do not know how to get this to look at the values as a wildcard

if($item.Package - AccountRef $Folder.Name){

$sourcefile = “L:\ClientDataSort\” + $item.Filename  #I Do not know how to get this to export to what's in column D as a location

$target = “L:\CliendDataSort” + $folder.Name

Move-Item$sourcefile$target

Write-Host“Folder $item.FileName moved sucessfully to $target”-ForegroundColor Green

}

}

}
```

Regards

Richard

```
$moveTargets = @{}

$csvFile = '.\ClientDataSort.csv'
$sourceFolder = 'L:\ClientSort'

foreach ($record in Import-Csv -Path $csvFile)
{
$moveTargets[$record.AccountRef] = $record.FileSortLocation
}

Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder |
ForEach-Object {
$pdfFile = $_
if ($pdfFile.Name -match '^[^_]*_([^_]*)_[^_]*\.pdf$')
{
    $accountRef = $matches[1]
    $target = $moveTargets[$accountRef]

    if ($target)
    {
        Move-Item -Path $pdfFile.FullName -Destination $target
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: Updated with the code as requested, I really am unsure where to go next with this?

Comment: Your description of the problem is rather terrible. This is how I see it 1) You have files in `L:\ClientSort`. You want to match the name of each file against column `A`(called Package?) in `L:\ClientDataSort.csv` 2) If matched, you want to move the file to location in column `D`(called FileName? Is this a path to a folder?).

Comment: Hi RAF, thanks for looking at this I have managed to get to the bottom of the issue sometimes starting again is the best course of action.

Comment: Good stuff, you should post your answer as an answer rather than as part of the question. Nice use of regex and hashtables too.