# Powershell Rename & Move Files via CSV

Tags: file, powershell

I've tried searching for a solution to my dilemma, I've even tried combining a few solutions from here, but have had no success.

My dilemma is that I download a lot of files all at once, and they tend to be given non descriptive names. I want a script that will read a CSV file with the following format:

current path,new path

Where current path is the full current path including file name, and new path is the full new path including file name.

I need this as a powershell script preferably, since that's my default, though cmd is usable as well. I'm currently running Windows 8.1 if that's needed info.

I would include the code I've already tried, but that would take up a lot of space, and I'm on my phone.

Comment: Look up `Import-Csv`, and then `Foreach-Object`

Comment: You should be able to just copy paste some so code to do that. Where do you stuck?

Comment: The fact that I know next to nothing about powershell, and only really know once command which pipes a list of files to a txt file xd

Comment: It is unlikely that anyone here is going to just write your code for you.  You might have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/23362557 which is very similar to your problem, and see if you can adapt it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a rule I wouldn't do this, but I had this one from a while back, it should put you on the right track.

```
 $Files = "Path:\to\Files\"
   $CSV = "Path:\to\CSV\file.csv"
   $Import = import-csv $CSV
   $RENAME = get-childitem $Files
   $Import | % {
     $old = $_.old #Column Title for Old file name
     $new = $_.new #Column Title for New file name
     rename-item $old $new
   }
```